# save Lat and Lng when click on map

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to use the below code to save "lat" and "lng" value when user clicks on map but

I get "undefined" for both lat and lng !!!

"latStorage" is the storage name where I want to store the lat

"lngStorage" is the storage name where I want to store the lng

```
var placedMarkers = 0;
var availableMarkersToPlace = 1; 
setTimeout( function(){
    if(placedMarkers >= availableMarkersToPlace) 
        return; 
    placedMarkers++; 
    var map = Appery("google_map").gmap; 
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        localStorage.setItem('latStorage', event.latLng.lat); 
        localStorage.setItem('lngStorage', event.latLng.Lng); 
        placeMarker(event.latLng,map); 
        alert (event.latLng); 
    }); 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You should probably add the Google maps tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invoice `lat` and `lng` which are functions:

```
localStorage.setItem('latStorage', event.latLng.lat());
localStorage.setItem('lngStorage', event.latLng.lng());
```

Answer (score 3):

`lat` and `lng` are functions. Try to call them like this:

`event.latLng.lat()` and `event.latLng.lng()`